# Create documents, sub collections in Firestore via flutter on screen loads

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stateful

I want to achieve is when flutter screen loads a document should create in firestore in following order.

```
Document > Sub Collection > Document > Data Fields
```

I manage to create documents and sub collections in above order, but the first `Document` appear in `italic`. That's because the `child` collection, documents creating before `parent` document created.

But I couldn't able to fix the issue. I've modified the code now it's not even creating the document. Before this It created in `italic` mode. Now it's not at all.

Here is the code.

```
getCurrentUser().then((user) {
  DocumentReference todayReference = firestoreInstance.collection('attendance').document(todayDate);

  firestoreInstance.collection('profiles').where('user_id', isEqualTo: user).snapshots().listen((onData) {
    onData.documents.forEach((f) {
      CollectionReference todaySubCollection = todayReference.collection(f.documentID);

      DocumentReference attendanceReference = todaySubCollection.document(f["name"].toString().toLowerCase());

      Map<String,dynamic> mapData = new Map<String,dynamic>();

      mapData['attendance_status'] = true;
      mapData['in'] = true;
      mapData['out'] = true;

      firestoreInstance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        await transaction.set(attendanceReference, mapData);
      }); 

    });
  });
});
```

Here `getCurrentUser()` is returning the logged in `user id`.

Each `profiles` assigned to a `user`.

So, What I'm trying to do is, once user logged in a document should create under `attendance` collection named `today's date`.

Then looping through each `profiles` where `user_id` is matched with logged in user, the matching results will be store as `sub collection` under `today's date` with profiles `name` field.

Then under the `name` (document), a transaction needs to run to set details like `attendance_status`, `in` & `out`.

Following images will show how previously documents created.

[image: image 01]
[image: image 02]

I need to find a way to create documents, collection without in `italic` mode. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution!. First we need let parent document to be created successfully. In-order to do that. We can set some data to the parent document. Then go head with creating sub collections and more. `firestoreInstance.collection('attendance').document(todayDate).setData({
        'description' : 'This is a short description',
      });`

Answer (score 1):

"Italicized" documents are virtual/non-existent as mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents). If a document only has a sub-collection, it will be a virtual/non-existent document. A workaround for this is by writing fields in the document, like what you've mentioned in the comments.